# Dart - List of generic subclasses

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a way to create a list of references of subclasses and be able to construct them later.

Example :

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

abstract class Animal{
  abstract String sound;
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  @override
  String sound = "woaf";
}

class Cat extends Animal{
  @override
  String sound = "meow";
}

void main() {
  test('Subclasses', () {
    final l = [Dog, Cat];
    l.forEach((E) { 
      print(E().sound); // doesn't work
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dart's reflection features in `dart:mirrors`?

Comment: ...that said, **why** do you want this information? What do you mean by "construct them later"? Aren't you using an IDE?

Comment: Ok, I'll check `dart:mirrors`out. Thanks

Comment: A simple alternative without the need for `dart:mirrors` would be to create a list of constructor functions instead, for example `[Dog.new, Cat.new]`. The default constructor is `.new`, if you had a named constructor it would be `.constructorName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of references to subclasses and construct instances of them later using the Type references.

```dart
abstract class Animal {
  String get sound;
  
  factory Animal(Type type) {
    if (type == Dog) {
      return Dog();
    } else if (type == Cat) {
      return Cat();
    }

    throw ArgumentError('Invalid type: $type');
  }
}

class Dog implements Animal {
  @override
  String get sound => "woaf";
}

class Cat implements Animal {
  @override
  String get sound => "meow";
}

void main() {
  test('Subclasses', () {
    final l = [Dog, Cat];

    l.forEach((Type type) {
      print(Animal(type).sound);
    });
  });
}
```